# How to install rsh in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

how to install rsh in ubuntu ? rsh stands for restricted shell and not remote shell.

I am using ubuntu saucy.

Answer (score 2):

Try;

For server install rsh-server

```
sudo apt-get install rsh-server
```

For client install rsh-client

```
sudo apt-get install rsh-client
```

Comment: Wrong . I did mention already that its not remote server. Its .restricted server

Comment: If your restrict server have no internet connection so you can use usb copy install package which you download on another machine and using dpkg install it.

Please let me know if I get it wrong. I though it's restricted server by setup firewall but still have internet connection for install package.

Comment: You are talking something that really dont belong to my question.